# Remove Class when reaching top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script to add a drop shadow and position fixed to my header. However, when an user scrolls all the way back to the top how do I remove the class?

Here my script:

```
$(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top_offset) {
      $('.top_head_separator').addClass('fixed-top fade-in');
  }
});
```

How do I reverse this when scroll bar is at very top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether `top_offset` is `0` and use `removeClass` if so.

[jsFiddle showing the value of top_offset](http://jsfiddle.net/rKwKd/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var top_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top_offset == 0) {
            $('.top_head_separator').removeClass('fixed-top fade-in');
        } else {
            $('.top_head_separator').addClass('fixed-top fade-in');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! By chance could you help with my [other question]?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319394/fade-in-box-shadow-using-css-3)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top_offset === 0)
      $('.top_head_separator').addClass('fixed-top fade-in');
    else if (top_offset > 100) // or something else
      $('.top_head_separator').removeClass('fixed-top fade-in');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `window.pageYOffset;` to get the current scroll position.
- Check whether current position is the top & use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)